# LINQ to SQL simple query to get single int value

Tags: linq

```
IQueryable<double?> query = (from t in ctx.MyList orderby t.MyNums select t.MyNums).Take(1);
IQueryable<double> q2 = query.Cast<double>();
IEnumerator<double> enumerator = q2.GetEnumerator();

while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    double d = enumerator.Current;
    return System.Convert.ToInt32(d);
}
```

The context for the above code is that I'm attempting to get the greatest integer value from a SharePoint list column. SharePoint seems to treat all list item values as "Number" so that's the reason that I initially had "double?" and not "int?". How could I write that query better? Also, at the moment, it doesn't work at all.. it says "Can only specify query options (orderby, where, take, skip) after last navigation." What does that mean? Thanks..

**Additional Information e.g. "Why Max() doesn't work in SharePoint Web Services"**

Go to the following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd673933.aspx. The note contained there says the following:

> The set of queries expressible in the LINQ syntax is broader than those enabled in the representational state transfer (REST)-based URI syntax that is used by data services. A NotSupportedException is raised when the query cannot be mapped to a URI in the target data service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to check for a null value in case all items in the list are null

```
return (int)(ctx.MyList.Max(x => x.MyNums) ?? 0);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm embarrassed now that I didn't notice that method.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try using `Max` instead?

```
double max = ctx.MyList.Max(t => t.MyNums);
return (int) max;
```

Comment: "cannot implicitly convert type double? to double.." .. edit: adding an explicit cast to (double) right before ctx.MyList did the trick. thanks.